# Proving Skip List probability

Tags: algorithm, random, skip, skip-lists

How can I prove that, with a Skip List variant of nodes deciding their height by throwing a six-sided (If the die takes any of the values 2 through 6, then the node promotes itself to the next level. The node finalizes its level when the die roll is 1.), if there are n nodes then the number of lists O(log n) with probability at least `1 − 1/n` (show that the probability any node is in at most `c*logn` levels, where `c`, some constant, is `>= 1 - 1/n`)

Comment: I don't follow: "the number of lists O(log n)" - do you mean that the maximum level a node has promoted itself to, or the average level, is constant * log(n)? Or the number of levels with non-zero population? I don't think you mean complexity here. Isn't this just a [geometric sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression)? Your last value looks like the sum-to-infinity of a geometric sequence.

Comment: its proving that the probability any node is in at most c*logn levels, where c is some constant, is >= 1 - 1/n

Comment: It's really not all that different from the proof for a d2.